# Nginx with multiple proxy_pass loca

Tags: windows, spring-boot, nginx

I have Nginx on Windows 10 and have 2 Spring boot APIs (one running on port 8080 and other on 8081) I want to expose via Nginx, but I want both APIs to be accessed from the same server name and port number but just different paths. For instance when the I use `localhost:80/users` I go to API with port 8080 and if I go to `localhost:80/inventory` I go to the API with 8081. I tried the below

```
server{
    listen          80;
    server_name     localhost;

     location /users {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

    location /inventory {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    }
}
```

But I can not seem to get it to do what I expect, I believe I am missing something. If I create two server objects as below with different port numbers it works but that is not what I prefer.

```
server{
    listen          80;
    server_name     localhost;

     location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}

server{
    listen          81;
    server_name     localhost;

     location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
}
```

I am not sure what else I need to change in order to make it work I want, but any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to determine the issue and not fully understanding what the location block do.

The Springboot API enpoints did not include users and inventory from the start and started with api/users and api/inventory. When removing the api in the Springboot API enpoints it worked as expected. I added api back to the enpoints changed the nginx config as below and also worked

```
server{
  listen          80;
  server_name     localhost;

 location /api/users {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}

location /api/inventory {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
}
```

}